# Is jigsaw identification enough to render a piece of information DPA-subject “personal data“?

Tags: gdpr, privacy, data-protection, personal-information

In some legal contexts there is the notion of “jigsaw identification,” that is pieces of information that could allow certain people if adequately placed and privileged to other pieces of information to identify a subject who is otherwise in principle to be kept anonymous. In other words, when put together with other “pieces of the jigsaw puzzle,” they could form a full picture of who the subject is.

Meanwhile for a piece of information to be subject to the data protection act’s rights of access it must be a data subject’s personal data. This is apparently defined as data from which the person can in any way be personally identified.

The question is, suppose an organisation holds rows in a data table which concern for example food deliveries made and the dishes ordered with the dates of the orders as well as a broadly anonymous numeric customer ID.

THis customer ID would be meaningless to members of the general public. But if it got into the right hands like for example those of the particular delivery man who delivered that order, then he would easily be able to either mentally recall or cross reference in his order book the name of the customer and their address.

Is the row recording this customer’s order then the customer’s “personal data” and thus subject to the rigours of the data protection act?

Comment: The ID alone is personal information - there is no "jigsaw" involved.